# regular expression for url

Tags: regex, url, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

what is the regular expression for a url without `http://www.`? i'd like to validate whether it is uri or not when the user enters the uri name