# Regular Expression to parse string url links

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, url, url-rewriting

I am looking for a way to parse url link into following segments without using `System.Uri`

> /Default.aspx/123/test?var1=val1

I need to break down this url link into values:

1. File
2. PathInfo
3. Querystring

Comment: possible duplicate of [regular expression for url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string pattern= "\b(?<protocol>https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help)://(?<domain>[-A-Z0-9.]+)(?<file>/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?<parameters>\?[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?"
```

This will generate named groups check for  for what you want to extract

Answer (score 2):

Here's one:

```
string pattern = @"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)"
```

[Origin Link](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm)

Comment: it is a bad practice just posting links. If the link broke your answer says nothing

Comment: fair enough. but you'd get the same answer by googling "regular expression url", to take credit for their work seems ...wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code:

```
   var match = Regex.Match(internalUrl,
                            @"^\/([\w|\/|\-|\,|\s]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})([\w|\/|\-|\,|\s]*)\??(.*)",
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline |
                            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var filePath = match.Groups[1].Value;
        var fileExtention = match.Groups[2].Value;
        var pathInfo = match.Groups[3].Value;
        var queryString = match.Groups[4].Value;

        log.Debug("FilePath: " + filePath);
        log.Debug("FileExtention: " + fileExtention);
        log.Debug("PathInfo: " + pathInfo);
        log.Debug("QueryString: " + queryString);
    }
```