# How would I use NSRegularExpression where if a section is detected and replaced, it won't be done to again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, markdown, nsregularexpression

I have an issue where I want to parse some Markdown, and when I try to parse text with emphasis, where the text wrapped in underscores is to be emphasized (such as `this is some _emphasized_ text`).

However links also have underscores in them, such as `http://example.com/text_with_underscores/`, and currently my regular expression would pick up `_with_` as an attempt at emphasized text.

Obviously I don't want it to, and as text with emphasis in the middle of it is valid (such as `longword*with*emphasis` being valid), my go to solution is to parse links first, and almost "mark" those replacements to not be touched again. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to replace _ with *??

Comment: @HussainShabbir HTML, in this case. So `_word_` becomes `<em>word</em>`.

Comment: So you want like this -with- becomes <em>with</em> right??

Comment: @HussainShabbir Correct.

Comment: you want to replace _emphasized_ with <em>emphasized</em> in your string?using regex

Comment: @johnykumar Correct.

Comment: wait i m implementing.

Comment: Here at SO, "longword*with*emphasis" emphasizes the `with`, but "longword_with_emphasis" doesn't.  Is that a customization?

Comment: Can you tell us what the RE is you are using to match URLs (that is the text you wish to "mark")?

Comment: Also can you confirm that you want to convert, say, "http://example.com/text_with_underscores/ \_emph\_" to "http://example.com/text_with_underscores/ <em>emph</em>"?

Comment: @AlanMoore I'm unsure what you're asking. I can't use that to differentiate as URLs with asterisks are valid.

Comment: @CRD That's exactly it.

Comment: @DougSmith - Thanks, added a solution for you - but you'll need to work on it to address Markdown escapes

Comment: I was saying maybe you shouldn't be treating the underscores in "longword_with_emphasis" specially to start with.  But on second thought, the URL should already have been converted to a link, and you shouldn't be looking at it again.  This is essentially a lexing job, and lexers typically do their job all in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

One solution you can implement like this:-

```
NSString *yourStr=@"this is some _emphasized_ text";
NSMutableString *mutStr=[NSMutableString string];
NSUInteger count=0;
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<yourStr.length; i++)
{
    unichar c =[yourStr characterAtIndex:i];
    if ((c=='_') && (count==0))
    {
    [mutStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"<em>"]];
        count++;
    }
    else if ((c=='_') && (count>0))
    {
        [mutStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"</em>"]];
        count=0;
    }
    else
    {
        [mutStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",c]];
    }

}
NSLog(@"%@",mutStr);
```

Output:-

```
this is some <em>emphasized</em> text
```

Comment: Wait, that output doesn't make sense. As I said in the original post, it should not do it for URLs, but it should for non-URLs. I would want a URL to be parsed as one without adding random emphasis, and emphasized text to be emphasized it.

Answer (score 0):

```
__block NSString *yourString = @"media_w940996738_ _help_  476.mp3";
NSError *error = NULL;
__block NSString *yourNewString;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([_])\\w+([_])" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

  yourNewString=[NSString stringWithString:yourString];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

    // detect

    NSString *subString = [yourString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]];
    NSRange range=[match rangeAtIndex:0];
    range.location+=1;
    range.length-=2;
    //print
    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<em>%@</em>",[yourString substringWithRange:range] ];
    yourNewString = [yourNewString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:subString withString:string];


}];
```

Comment: How does this *not* match _'s in URLs?

Comment: you can use your url as string

Answer (score 0):

First a more usual way to do processing like this would be to tokenise the input; this both makes handling each kind of token easier and is probably more efficient for large inputs. That said, here is how to solve your problem using regular expressions.

Consider:

1. `matchesInString:options:range` returns all the *non-overlapping* matches for a regular expression.
2. Regular expressions are built from smaller regular expressions and can contain alternatives. So if you have *REemphasis* which matches strings to emphasise and *REurl* which matches URLs, then (*REemphasis*)|(*REurl*) matches both.
3. `NSTextCheckingResult`, instances of which are returned by `matchesInString:options:range`, reports the range of each *group* in the match, and if a group does not occur in the result due to alternatives in the pattern then the group's `NSRange.location` is set to `NSNotFound`. So for the above pattern, (*REemphasis*)|(*REurl*), if group 1 is `NSNotFound` the match is for the *REurl* alternative otherwise it is for *REemphasis* alternative.
4. The method `replacementStringForResult:inString:offset:template` will return the replacement string for a match based on the template (*aka* the replacement pattern).

The above is enough to write an algorithm to do what you want. Here is some sample code:

```
- (NSString *) convert:(NSString *)input
{
   NSString *emphPat = @"(_([^_]+)_)"; // note this pattern does NOT allow for markdown's \_ escapes - that needs to be addressed
   NSString *emphRepl = @"<em>$2</em>";

   // a pattern for urls - use whatever suits
   // this one is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137865/iphone-reg-exp-for-url-validity
   NSString *urlPat = @"([hH][tT][tT][pP][sS]?:\\/\\/[^ ,'\">\\]\\)]*[^\\. ,'\">\\]\\)])";

   // construct a pattern which matches emphPat OR urlPat
   // emphPat is first so its two groups are numbered 1 & 2 in the resulting match
   NSString *comboPat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@", emphPat, urlPat];

   // build the re
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:comboPat options:0 error:&error];
   // check for error - omitted

   // get all the matches - includes both urls and text to be emphasised
   NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)];

   NSInteger offset = 0;                        // will track the change in size
   NSMutableString *output = input.mutableCopy; // mutuable copy of input to modify to produce output

   for (NSTextCheckingResult *aMatch in matches)
   {
      NSRange first = [aMatch rangeAtIndex:1];

      if (first.location != NSNotFound)
      {
         // the first group has been matched => that is the emphPat (which contains the first two groups)

         // determine the replacement string
         NSString *replacement = [re replacementStringForResult:aMatch inString:output offset:offset template:emphRepl];

         NSRange whole = aMatch.range;                // original range of the match
         whole.location += offset;                    // add in the offset to allow for previous replacements
         offset += replacement.length - whole.length; // modify the offset to allow for the length change caused by this replacement

         // perform the replacement
         [output replaceCharactersInRange:whole withString:replacement];
      }
   }

   return output;
}
```

**Note** the above does not allow for Markdown's \_ escape sequence and you need to address that. You probably also need to consider the RE used for URLs - one was just plucked from SO and hasn't been tested properly.

The above will convert

> http://example.com/text_with_underscores _emph_

to

> http://example.com/text_with_underscores <em>emph</em>

HTH