# how to automatically convert a web address into a hyperlink when binding to asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a column in my database whose value is e.g. "website, deployment,http://www.qihub.scot.nhs.uk, test" and on my webpage I m using asp:Literal control to bind it. If part of this column value is **http** then how can we automatically make it a hyperlink so that its clickable.

Markup

```
<p>
     <strong>Tags: </strong>
     <asp:Literal id="m_eventTags"    runat=server />
</p>

private void PopulateForm()
{
   //blabla
   m_eventTags.Text = theReader.GetString(10);
}
```

Comment: can we see your markup?

Comment: if you notice in the question above within double quotes, the URL(http://www.qihub.scot.nhs.uk") is clickable but the rest of it is a plain text. This is what I want for this column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown us your code so it's hard to give an answer, but I suspect that an ternary if coupled with a string.Contains will do the trick:

```
myValue.Contains("http") ? "<a href='" + myValue + "'>" + myValue + "</a>" : myvalue;
```

UPDATE:  I just noticed that your url is embedded in a string of text.  In order to peel out the URL you will probably need to use regex.  I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url) which will probably help with that.