# URL Regular Expression Update

Tags: c#, php

I am using the following expression for URL validation.

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

However, when I have

```
"httpcolonforwardslashessite" (colon = : and foward slashes = //)
```

it still passes it as a url. how can I modify the above expression to make sure that there is ".com/net" at the end?

Thank you

tldr: I want to check for .com or .net at the end of url. What changes can I make to above exp to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url

Comment: thanks...but that got a bit more complicated than I was hoping for...very complex regex. What can I do to add a "clause" at the end that check for .com or .net at the end? I want url with http://google to be rejected

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use inbuilt function, instead of Regex?

[`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx) Method can help you.

This method

- returns a `Boolean` value that is `true` if the `Uri` was successfully created; otherwise, `false`.
- can check different kinds of urls like Absolute or/and Relative using an overload that accepts [`UriKind Enumeration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind.aspx) as a parameter.

Comment: Seriously, I learn something new every day on this site, without even asking anything :D

Comment: @Nolonar Everyone learns here...from a newbie to over-experienced.

Comment: Already tried that...fails for some criteria where this exp passes. :(

Comment: @user1569220 What criteria? Let ne know? I am using this for a long time and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @user1569220 I'm curious as well, can you give us a URL that won't work with this?

Comment: h t t P : / / www . g o o g l e (all together)

Comment: @user1569220 So you mean `http://www.google` will work, but shouldn't? Or it won't work, but should?

Comment: it shouldn't pass (according to what I am trying to do)...but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want .com, this will work:

```
^(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-])/?\.com([/\w \.!"£$%^&\(\)\*])*
```

or this one to include not just .com [from here](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=146)

```
^(http|https)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to escape that `.`?

Comment: what about .com or .net (not just .com)