# How to detect and remove URLs a sentence?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, url

Is it possible to detect and remove any kind of URLs in a sentence?

For example:

```
Today,wheather is cold.But I want to out. http://weathers.com..... And I will take a cup of tea...
```

should become

```
Today,wheather is cold.But I want to out. And I will take a cup of tea...
```

Comment: Use a regex. Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url#answer-8234912

Comment: define **any kind of urls** pls. `https://? file:///? ftp://? scp://? smb://.. ... ?`

Comment: https://? file:///? ftp://? scp://? smb://,...and also shorted urls that usually use on twitter

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how comprehensive you want the matching process to be. You can try using something as simple as

```
str.replaceAll("http://[^\\s]+", "")
```

e.g.

```
System.out.println("Today,wheather is cold.But I want to out. "
        + "http://weathers.com..... And I will take a cup of tea..."
        .replaceAll("http://[^\\s]+", ""));
```

```
Today,wheather is cold.But I want to out.  And I will take a cup of tea...
```

---

If you want something more robust to match valid URLs, use a fuller URL regular expression:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

For even more thorough matching, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url/190405#190405) answer.

Comment: The real URL (IRI) seems more complicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2040040

Comment: @johnchen902 Yes, I referenced that question in the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the bellow regular expression

```
((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

for matching your valid `URL` and the following code should do, what you want:

```
    String str = "Today,wheather is cold. But I want to out. http://weathers.com..... And I will take a cup of tea";
    String regularExpression = "(((http|ftp|https):\\/\\/)?[\\w\\-_]+(\\.[\\w\\-_]+)+([\\w\\-\\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\\+#]*[\\w\\-\\@?^=%&amp;/~\\+#])?)";
    str = str.replaceAll(regularExpression,"");
    System.out.println(str);
```

**Edit:**

However this regular expression will not work for all types of URL's, because its too much complicated and hard to find the perfect regular expressions to match all types of URL.