# What is the javascript REGEX for this pattern: url(**someurl**)

Tags: javascript, regex, url, expression

example:

url(http://xevens.dev/images/slider-bg.jpg)

I need the value inside the parenthesis. I could just strip out the 'url(' and ')' parts but its ugly. I want this in regex.

Help please

Comment: "_Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work."_ -- StackOverflow.

Comment: Why regex? Is your current solution working? Seems like splitting should do...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use a regex so much? It seems that the obvious solution is to just use `substring`:

```
function getUrl(urlString) {
    return urlString.substring(
        urlString.indexOf('(') + 1, 
        urlString.lastIndexOf(')'))
}
```

Example of using it:

```
var test = 'url(http://xevens.dev/images/slider-bg.jpg)';
console.log(getUrl(test));
```

**Don't forget that a url can contain parenthesis.** Which is what makes the Regex solution  tricky.

Answer (score 0):

```
^url\(.*\)$ # Will match any string starting by "url(" and ending by ")". Replace the "*" by "+" if you want to ignore the "url()" match
```

But there are more efficients ways to do it. For example you can split on parenthesis since an url cannot contain parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @RobH.

Then you can check if the URL is valid with a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url).

You should avoid to use regular expressions everywhere, like for your url() prefix/suffix. Regular expressions are very difficult to read, to understand and to maintain.