# C++11 regex_error - why? (code: 2)

Tags: c++, regex, boost, c++11, escaping

Why does this C++11 code throw a regex_error?

```
string s{R"((http)(s)?(:\/\/)(www\.)?([^ ]*))"};
regex r{s}; // throws regex_error
```

I've been looking all over the internet for correct escaping and I've tried multiple combinations, but I think my escaping is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using GNU libstdc++, `<regex>` is broken, last time I checked.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I am, using GCC 4.8.1. - So, is the only other possibility, excluding libc++, Boost?

Comment: I would just use Boost.

Comment: If you're looking for a good regex for URLs, Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url)  out:

Comment: There's good ol' PCRE++ too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC apparently does not really support regular expressions yet.
See the status page: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

As suggested by comments, you may be best off using boost for now. Clang with libc++ already has regexes too.