# Javascript random redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

so my situation is as follows:

I wrote a submission system in php that writes to a textfile rather than a database, the idea of the system is people submit their url to the textfile and then when that script is called on a page, it redirects to a random address out of the textfile; the problem is, I don't know how to make javascript read from the text file and then pick a line to redirect to.

Actually, just to clarify, I know how to make javascript read from the text file; but I have NO idea how id write a function to pick a url from the file and forward to it.

Seeing as I hit this road block a couple of days ago, the only way I have been handling submissions is checking the text file every 12 hours for new submissions and then manually adding them to this code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
var howMany = 38; 
var page = new Array(howMany+1);

page[0]="http://gproxy.nl/";
page[1]="http://homeproxy.me/";
page[2]="http://proxyturbo.com/";
page[3]="http://www.lblocker.info/";
page[4]="http://goprivate.eu/";
page[5]="http://jsproxy.com/";
page[6]="http://openthis.eu/";
page[7]="http://proxy4home.info/";
page[8]="http://dedicatedipaddress.net/";
page[9]="https://www.4everproxy.com/";
page[10]="http://www.surfsearch.info/";
page[11]="http://www.leaveproxy.com/";
page[12]="http://proxyecole.fr/";
page[13]="http://newipnow.com/";
page[14]="http://www.hiddenmode.info/";
page[15]="https://europrox.org/";
page[16]="https://www.4everproxy.com/";
page[17]="https://goingthere.org/";
page[18]="http://xuxor.com/";
page[19]="http://033b.com/";
page[20]="http://thewebtunnel.com/";
page[21]="http://prox.phanteye.com/";
page[22]="http://www.hiddenall.info/";
page[23]="http://www.5966.info/";
page[24]="http://hideyoself.com/";
page[25]="http://prox.phanteye.com/";
page[26]="http://freevideoproxy.com/";
page[27]="http://thewebtunnel.com/";
page[28]="http://openthis.eu/";
page[29]="https://europrox.org/";
page[30]="http://xuxor.com/";
page[31]="https://incloak.com/";
page[32]="http://www.leaveproxy.com/";
page[33]="http://www.openunblocker.com/";
page[34]="http://post48.com";
page[35]="http://post48.com";
page[36]="http://inteproxy.com";
page[37]="http://208.73.23.59";
page[38]="http://hidemetoday.com/";


function rndnumber(){
var randscript = -1;
while (randscript < 0 || randscript > howMany || isNaN(randscript)){
randscript = parseInt(Math.random()*(howMany+1));
}
return randscript;
}
quo = rndnumber();
quox = page[quo];
window.location=(quox);
}, 1500);
```

I would be very grateful if someone would help me write the script or tell me what kind of function I should be googling to look up, googling "How to make javascript read from a textfile and redirect" doesn't really turn up much ; (

Many thanks!

Comment: While this isn't an answer, I feel the need to point out that JavaScript is completely different from Java, and thus this question should not be listed in the Java category.

Comment: Why doesn't work when the posted code is run? What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if php reads the file and send random link to the client instead of sending the whole text file full of urls.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, first, you'll need a regex to find the URLs in the file. I would refer to this SO post for that: [regular expression for url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url)

Once you have that, you can go to any URL with `window.location.href = 'http://google.com';`

So, you'll do something like this...

```
var urlPattern = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/g;
var urls = data.match(urlPattern);
if (urls) {
    window.location.href = urls[7];
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Or you can use a more simple regex like `var urlPat = /https?:\/\/[^'"]+/g`

Remember to use the `/g` flag with your regex to get all occurrences of the urls.