# How to identify #hashtag and "http://" link from a string in android

Tags: android, string

is it possible to find a #hashtag and an "http://" link from a string and color it ? I am using this in Android.

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found an answer and here is the way to do it :

```
        SpannableString hashtagintitle = new SpannableString(imageAndTexts1.get(position).getTitle());
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtagintitle);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            hashtagintitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);

        }
        textView.setText(hashtagintitle);
```

Comment: It only works for last hashtag in the textview. How can I make it mark all hashtags?

Comment: is there anyway to make it clickable too? I mean use it like a real <a> element in html

Answer (score 3):

if you want to divide **COMPOUND WORD** into its parts.

from

## **#hashtag#hashtag2#hashtag3**

to

## {hashtag, hashtag2, hashtag3}

You can use this code below.

```
public static List<String> getHashTags(String str) {
        Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(#[a-zA-Z0-9ğüşöçıİĞÜŞÖÇ]{2,50}\\b)");
        Matcher mat = MY_PATTERN.matcher(str);
        List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
        while (mat.find()) {
            strs.add(mat.group(1));
        }
        return strs;
    }
```

Comment: You Save my day man  +1
Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a list of all the #hashtags in your string

```
public static List<String> getHashTags(String str) {
    Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("#(\\S+)");
    Matcher mat = MY_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    while (mat.find()) {
        strs.add(mat.group(1));
    }
    return strs;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class to do more than hashtag and webpages. [Here](http://www.sourabhsoni.com/implementing-hashtags-in-android-application/) is an example on how you can find hashtags in textview and link it to another activity.

Answer (score -2):

You could match it using a regex.

[Heres the Class in Android for using Regexes.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

[I quickly found this writeup on matching hashtags](http://granades.com/2009/04/06/using-regular-expressions-to-match-twitter-users-and-hashtags/)

[And here's a SO question for matching URL's.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url)

Comment: I got that but what is the procedure to find that from String title ?