# URL validation using Regular Expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

There are so many post about url validation using regular expression. I got this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568244/url-validation-regex-url-just-valid-with-http) expression and create a function which validate url. Everything is working fine but i want "some.com" also **true**, which is i am getting **false**. I tried with some regular exp for **empty string** like **^$** but not working fine!

```
function is_url(url)
    {
        if(/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test(url))
            {
               return true
            }
            else
            {
               return false
            }
        }
```

Result:

https:\\www.some.com - **true**

http:\\www.some.com - **true**

http:\\some.com - **true**

www.some.com - **true**

some.com - **false** // i want this also true

Any Help?

Comment: This isn't an URL at all. At this point, why do a validation ?

Comment: jsut do `www` part optional like `(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.)?`

Comment: http:\anything is not a valid http url

Comment: try this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/

Comment: @mplungjan..edited now

Comment: @Grundy..thanx..it works

Comment: It works to validate malformed URLs with backslashes in them?

Comment: The canonical answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url.

Comment: Still wrong. URLs use forward slashes

Answer (score 1):

try validator.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

**isURL(str [, options])** - check if the string is an URL. options is an object which defaults to { protocols: ['http','https','ftp'], require_tld: true, require_protocol: false, allow_underscores: false, host_whitelist: false, host_blacklist: false, allow_trailing_dot: false, allow_protocol_relative_urls: false }.

bower install validator-js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/validator-js/validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var urlOptions = {protocols: ['http','https'], require_protocol: false, allow_underscores: false};

  console.log(validator.isURL('https://www.some.com', urlOptions));
  console.log(validator.isURL('http://www.some.com', urlOptions));
  console.log(validator.isURL('http://some.com', urlOptions));
  console.log(validator.isURL('www.some.com', urlOptions));
  console.log(validator.isURL('some.com', urlOptions));
</script>
```

here is results:

1. code: http://joxi.ru/vDr8ooZC3jQGA6
2. output: http://joxi.ru/gV2VGG4tOMgaAv