# Secure URL textarea

Tags: php, html, security

I have a textarea form where you can insert URLs which are passed through a function. But I can't figure out how to secure it against malicious code.

I found a way to check valid characters with `preg_match()` but since a URL can contain almost every character this isn't very useful.

Is there a way to check if the textarea only contains URLs or disable code execution all together?

Comment: What do you mean by "or disable code execution all together" ?

Comment: I passed some html code (form) in the textarea and the form was displayed on the page

Comment: you want only url to be passed from textrea?

Comment: Thats`s right! I'm a bit concerned about security when just passing everything to the function without checking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568244/url-validation-regex-url-just-valid-with-http

Comment: Take a look at, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/1547940#1547940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$input= htmlspecialchars($_POST['input']);
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks, I think that should be enough but not sure. Maybe I worry about nothing...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent HTML from being passed from the textarea, may be [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) can do the job.