# Regular Expression to validate URL?

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to write a regular expression to match the URL of a website. Apparently

```
(http:\/\/www.)([a-zA-Z0-9])(\.[a-zA-z])\/"\s
```

does not work. The URL has to start with `http://www.` and can have up to one or more alpha numeric characters.

Comment: Why not use the `URL` class?

Comment: You don't need to escape forward slashes in Java.

Answer (score 2):

What about type into the google : "regular expression url" and clik on the first result?

[regular expression for url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url)

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Commons' UrlValidator:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html