# notepad ++ replacement expression

Tags: replace, notepad++

Hi guys I really need some help,  I need to do a mass replace expression in files
I have a large list of urls which needs to be replaced.

I want to search files and replace each with the appropriate brand anchor link e.g.

http://www.example.com 
becomes

```
<a href=”http://www.example.com”> http://www.example.com</a>
```

I need to do this with a large list of urls in multiple files

I tried the following expression 
(1)|(2)|(3)
(?1a)(?2b)(?3c)
But It doesn’t work. This is beyond me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Search > Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   http:\/\/www\.\w+\.com
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   <a href="$0">$0</a>
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All in All Opened Documents`

You can test it and see the results at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qN3iW6).

**Important note:** matching URLs with regular expressions can be complicated! I gave you the simplest example matching only URLs like `http://www.example.com`. If you have more complicated stuff, let us know but showing some of your data! More info on this matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url).

**UPDATE**:

Let's make it slightly more complicated to match also 
`yoursite.com/index.php?remainingurl`

Find what:

```
    (?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(\w+\.\w{2,6})(?:\/\w+\.\w+(?:\?\w+)?)?\b
```

Replace:

```
    <a href="$0">$1</a>
```

Comment: Nice answer.
Just to add my contribution : $0 contains the whole matched string. If you have to get a substring, capture with parenthesis and use $1, $2...$N tokens. For example here if you only want to get the url domain (for <a> text).
Regex : http:\/\/www\.(\w+)\.com => <a href="$0">$1</a>

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, great answer. I’ve managed to get it working because it’s a number of specific urls in a large number of documents I still use the (site1)|(site2)|(site3)… In the find field and replace with <a href="$0">$0</a> as you suggested and it worked.
Thanks a lot, appreciated.

Comment: I have encountered a small problem, it works fine until there is a website with a php url with a question mark. 
For example http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?remainingurl any ideas how to find and replace these with a similar expression?
Thanks