# Match urlencoded data from file

Tags: python, ruby, regex, pcre

Is there a way to match a HTTP POST urlencoded data (Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded) in a file? The matched strings will contain only printable characters and urlencoded characters like `% A-F` and the variable sign `&` in HTTP POST/GET data and of course the `=` between variable name and variable content. As an example a random text with the data I need to match:

> Death there mirth way the noisy merit. Piqued shy spring nor six
>   though mutual living ask extent. Replying of dashwood advanced
>   ladyship smallest disposal or. Attempt offices own improve now see.
>   Called person are around county talked her esteem. Those fully these
>   way nay thing seems.
>   **website=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F&number=1037319821&comment=Test+mea&gender=male&submit=Submit**
>   Ye on properly handsome returned throwing am no whatever. In without
>   wishing he of picture no exposed talking minutes. Curiosity continual
>   belonging offending so explained it exquisite. Do remember to followed
>   yourself material mr recurred carriage. High drew west we no or at
>   john. About or given on witty event. Or sociable up material bachelor
>   bringing landlord confined. Busy so many in hung easy find well up. So
>   of exquisite my an explained remainder. Dashwood denoting securing be
>   on perceive my laughing so. 
>   **id=1234&variable=test&firstname=John&lastname=Doe&gender=male&submit=Submit**

The data to match is in bold. Tried many ways but couldn't find a regex with `%[A-F]{2}` `&` `=` or something to generically match them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url

Comment: to match the URL only but I need to match both strings in text in bold, one has no URL in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to get you most of the way there.

```
x = re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9%./]+=[^\s]+)")
out = x.findall(input_str)

# out = ['website=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F&number=1037319821&comment=Test+mea&gender=male&submit=Submit', 'id=1234&variable=test&firstname=John&lastname=Doe&gender=male&submit=Submit']'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this break if the query parameter **name** is URL-encoded?

Comment: Yes! That is what I mean. No, my string has already urlencoded data.

Comment: Added a % to the regexp. Works for me.