# Regular expression String for URL in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I would like to check *URL Validation* in JAVA with regular-expression. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url#comment-21819715) comment and I tried to use it in my code as follow...

```
private static final String PATTERN_URL = "/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:ww‌​w.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?‌​(?:[\w]*))?)/";
```

```
.....
if (!urlString.matches(PATTERN_URL)) {
  System.err.println("Invalid URL");
  return false;
}
```

But I got compile time exception for writing my `PATTERN_URL` variable. I have no idea how to format it and I am worried about will it become **invalid regex** if I have modified. Can anyone fix it for me without losing original ? Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex looks fine. You just need to format it for a Java string, by escaping all the escape-slashes:

`\` --> `\\`

Resulting in this:

```
"/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:ww‌​w.|[-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/.\\w-_]*)?\\??(?:[-\\+=&;%@.\\w_]*)#?‌​(?:[\\w]*))?)/"
```

After Java *interprets* this string into a `java.util.regex.Pattern`, it will strip out those extra escape-slashes and become exactly the regex you want. You can prove this by printing it:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile(PATTERN_URL));
```

Comment: yes , thanks for great help. What is different between `String.matches("regex")`and `java.util.Pattern.compile('regex')` ?

Comment: Not much, unless you need to do it over and over, then you'll want to go with the `Pattern` object, which avoids re-compiling the `Pattern`  every iteration (this is what `String.matches(s)` does behind the scenes). See the "typical invocation" at the top of this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: pls don't be mind , pls teach me  what would be more preferable because my another validation methods also used with `String.matches("regex")` unless I have know exatly about it. Thanks.

Comment: If you're doing it over and over again, use `Pattern` and `Matcher`. If you're only doing it once per execution, for example, then stick with `String.matches(s)`.

Comment: Now compile time error has fixed but validation result does not produce as expected.. what am I wrong ? It does no return **true** even `mail.google.com`. any suggestions ?